# How many spells require expensive components for each casting?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, spell-components

As someone who doesn't have much Pathfinder experience (and, in particular, is more used to various editions of D&D), I was surprised to read that [only seven spells in the SRD include the word "gp"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/204522/23036). And of those seven, not all of them consume the components: *alarm* uses a focus that's not consumed, *gentle repose* only costs gold if heightened to fifth level, and so on.

Are there really so few spells in Pathfinder 2e that consume expensive components with each casting? Or are there other spells which need these components but don't get caught in a search for "gp"? I'm not familiar enough with Pathfinder to know if there are obvious spells I'm missing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Mainly Rituals

Virtually all of the [ritual spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=777) that any character can learn to cast based on skill proficiency and take much longer to cast also have a cost component. [Expanding the search](https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?q=gp&include-types=ritual%3Bspell&display=list) in the linked answer to include ritual spells gives a result of 74 spells.

These include spells such as *[resurrect](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rituals.aspx?ID=20)* for bringing back the dead and all of the spells which create permanent minions.

Comment: Just to be extra clear to those not familiar with Pathfinder 2e: Rituals are NOT spells, unlike in D&D 5e. They're completely separate, but have a lot of effects that used to be relegated to spells.

Comment: @ESCE [Rituals](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rituals.aspx) are described as,  "an esoteric and complex spell that anyone can cast". Definitely work differently than rituals in 5e, but they are spells as far as PF2 is concerned.

Comment: It helps to make extra clear that it's not a class feature that gives them to you (Though some feats do make you better).  Otherwise very easy to think your barbarian has no place with them